# How do I export an asp:FormView ItemTemplate to an external file

Tags: c#, asp.net, external, itemtemplate, edititemtemplate

I have an asp:FormView like this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="foo" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      ... lots of code
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      ... lots more code
    </EditItemTemplate>
<asp:FormView>
```

I would like to move the templates out to separate files, if possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the code you have in the templates and add them to separate `.ascx` files. Then you can do this:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:FormView ID="foo" runat="server" OnInit="foo_Init">
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void foo_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foo.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("~/Controls/MyLayoutTemplate.ascx");
    foo.EditTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("~/Controls/MyEditTemplate.ascx");
}
```